# Gnome Shell close, etc. buttons look

Tags: gnome, window-buttons

I switched to Gnome Shell and edited gconf settings desktop>gnome>shell>windows button_layout=:minimize,maximize,close

The buttons are there, but they don't use the Gnome Shell theme anymore, but rather look like the ones in Unity (small round buttons, with close being orange and the other two white).

How do I make the buttons look like they should again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to restore your windows and gtk theme, install the gnome-tweak-tool and choose for all theme Adwaita. You can also enable the gnome-shell-extensions-user-themes in order to change your themes more easily. You can find a ppa with the extentions and instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html).

Comment: OK, silly me, I never realised I was using Radiance instead of Adwaita :D. Still, thank you very much for the useful software suggestions.

Comment: @mingos we all have been there ;) you are welcome.